# Is YEAR(x) and EXTRACT(YEAR FROM x) equivalent in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Is `YEAR(x)` and `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM x)` equivalent in MySQL?

It seems to be in all my experiments, but I am not sure if there are not any edge cases.

As an example: Those two queries return exactly the same result. But I am not sure if it's always true.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM '2009-07-02');
SELECT YEAR('2009-07-02');
```

Comment: The EXTRACT() function is used to return a single part of a date/time, such as year, month, day, hour, minute, etc. while MySQL YEAR() returns the year for a given date.

Comment: So, it should return the same thing?

Comment: The output would be the same ..:)

Comment: In databases where both are defined, they should return the same thing.

Comment: Why did you use Oracle tag with mysql?

Comment: @LalitKumarB: I did not, somebody else edited the question and added the tag, see the question history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`extract` is of course more flexible than `year`, but yes, the effect of `EXTRACT (YEAR FROM <date>)` is the same as `YEAR(<date>)`.